# How do I hide a div tag for a specific event or contribution page?

Tags: civievent, contribution-page, css

I would like to hide a specific `div` tag for a specific event or contribution page ID. I am not good with JS. So prefer CSS `display:none;` method. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was doing this the other day.  Have a look for the contribution page id div which wraps the form.

The following hides a section in the contribution page with id=2, but no other contribution pages...

> div.crm-contribution-page-id-2 div.editrow_custom_8-section {
> display: none;
> }

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks. Just for future ref for events it will be div.crm-event-id-362 div#pricesetTotal { display: none; }